# A misunderstanding in elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an even positive integer. $S_n={{n(n+1)}\over {2}}$. I know that the remainder of the euclidian division of $S_n$ by $n$ is $n/2$ since 
$$S_n=n*{n\over 2}+{n\over 2};\;\;\; 0\leq {n\over 2}<n $$ but I want to know what is wrong about the following reasoning:
${S_n\over n}={(n+1)\over 2}$ so the remainder of $S_n$ by $n$ is the same as the remainder of $n+1$ by $2$ and since $n+1$ is odd then this remainder is $1$. Thank you for your help!

Comment: $S_n$ need not be divisible by $n$ , eg take $n$=2. So applying division algo to  $S_n/n$ does not make sense.

Comment: One can almost get away with it. The remainder on division by $2$ is $1$,  so the leftover term is $1/2$. Now multiply by $n$ and we get $n/2$.  General comment: In a first exposure to number theory, arguing with fractions can be treacherous. It is better to keep expressions "flat", no fractions.  If we start with fractions, like when we are proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, go immediately from fractional form $(p/q)^2=2$ to flat form $p^2=2q^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is the remainder divided by n.  The other is the remainder divided by 2.

The remainders are not the same.  The remainders divided by the divisor are the same.  That is $remainder(\frac {S_n}{n})/n  = remainder(\frac {n + 1}{2})/2$

Think of this.

12/8 has remainder 4. 6/4 has remainder 2.  And 3/2 has remainder 1.

4/8 = 2/4 = 1/2 but 4 does not equal 2 does not equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

$S_n/n$ does not mean "the remainder in the euclidean division of $S_n$ by $n$", but "the fraction whose numerator is $S_n$ and whose denominator is $n$".

$S_n/n = (n+1)/2$ means that those two fractions are equal (or that $2S_n = n(n+1)$ if you want to only talk about integers). It has *absolutely nothing* to do with the remainders of the respective divisions.

Comment: Well, it has a *little* to do with the remainders.  When you divide p into q the remainder will be proportional (but *definitely* not equal) to dividing np into nq.